# followup to: Page begins with number, WordPress adds 2

Tags: permalinks

question: 
is there truly no workaround to wp pages (not posts) adding '-2' to numeric urls, when there's no naming conflict (ie, no conflict such as as a file or folder, of any sort, with the same numbers)?

background:
i changed a html site to wp.  i'm building wp pages, not posts. urls with numbers (domain.com/1458 or domain.com/10890), automatically get a '-2' added to the end (domain.com/1458-2).  urls with no numbers do NOT get the '-2' added.  the html site was deleted;  there's nothing in Trash; no pics or other files pose a conflict.
i have zero backend knowledge but for the first time, ventured into phpMyAdmin db.  under the db heading, "_posts",  i found '-2' pinned to, for example, 1458-2.  i removed the '-2', saved, changed the permalink in wp and the issue resolved for a day or two.  then the '-2' reappeared.

great resource: 
this article seems to suggest that there's no workaround:  [Page begins with number, WordPress adds 2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290587/page-begins-with-number-wordpress-adds-2)

thx:
obviously, i'll have to add text to the numeric urls unless you have a workaround.  apologies for the long message.

Comment: So what is your question?  As your linked post suggests there doesn't seem to be an easy fix for this.

Comment: i was not clear. i will edit the post.  thx